# Funny noise coming out my car AC

Tags: ac

i've been getting this noise when i turn on the AC

Sometimes the noise would come and go, and it's not heard most times

It appears once in a while when i turn on the AC

What could be causing this noise? And what's the name for the sound that my ac makes ?

Please listen to the audio from this link >> https://www.justbeamit.com/yasqj

Comment: The link says it no longer exists. Could you edit your question and fix that? What is the year/make/model of the car in question?